# Cant scrape this website am i using the wrong tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the website for product names, prices and roast and when I try to do the same .

the out put is either "[]" or None

```
website = requests.get("https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/collections/coffee-beans")
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content,"html.parser")
coffees = soup.select("div",class_ ="product-details producteMH")
for coffee in coffees:
    name = coffee.find("h5",class_="uk-margin-small-top uk-margin-remove-bottom uk-text-uppercase")
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your selectors aren't working is because the data is loaded in Javascript, you can see this if you print soup. A way around this is to pull that data load it as json and query it that way:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

website = requests.get("https://www.thirdwavecoffeeroasters.com/collections/coffee-beans")
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content,"html.parser")

script_tag = str(soup.select('script')[17]).split("var meta = ")[-1].split('for (var attr')[0].replace(';', '', -1)
json_data = json.loads(script_tag)

print(json_data)
```

Once you have the json data you can target the specifics you want like json_data['products'][0] will display the first vendors information.